# Find a keyword in a Div, then get the string after colon, and turn it to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, search

Trying to figure out how to do this in jquery, javascript or php...
I have a div, or a p tag with text inside it.
For example:

```
<p>John likes math.  John sid: CA1001 Susie likes English: Susie sid: CA1002</p>
```

What I am trying to do is first find all the sid:(s) within the paragraph or div tag.  Each one found, I want to get the id string in front of the colon which the id will have 6 characters. Then, turn that id string into a variable, so this way I can replace the the id number with a link to go along with it.
As example:

```
<a href='http://www.website.com/studentinformation?id=$studentid'>CA1001</a>
```

Something sort of like that.  So this way each time an id comes up within that div, my code will turn the id to links.  Is that possible??

Comment: That's possible. Keep in mind that while JS would work, it would also mean that users with JS disabled won't get links. Hence, I'd suggest doing it server-side. Now, the question is: where are these strings coming from? If you are generating these, I would recommend generating links out of them in the first place instead of doing the replacement in a second step.

Comment: where are the strings coming from

Comment: As other comments - generate the `p` as required, eg `<p data-sid='CA1001'>...`   But sounds like you're parsing some other data that's generating the `p`'s in the first place - look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome... Thank you...  Trying to get my memory back on coding again...  I ll try it both javascript and server side...

Now if I wanted to put it in one div on the page... I ll probably need to create an id with that div tag like:

```
 <div id="test">This is my text that has sid: CA0056<br /> This is my text that is second has another sid: CA0055</div>
```

So then I want to do in the javascript is to...

```
 var src_str = $("#test");
 var theHtml = src_str.html();
```

Is that correct for javascript????   How to on a particular div in php?

Comment: `var pattern = /sid: (.{6})/g;
src_str.html(stc_str.html().replace(pattern, '<a href="http://www.website.com/studentinformation?id=$1">$1</a>'));`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use regular expression.

In your case you said all sids are in the following format

```
sid:
space
6 digits or chacters
```

So regex would be something like this `/sid: (.{6})/g`

After that you need to replace text in your p or div or other elements with a link and ID which regex will find.

```
var pattern = /sid: (.{6})/g; // pattern to match sid: 000000
$('p').each(function(i,e) {
    // find matches and replace
    $(e).html($(e).html().replace(pattern, '<a href="http://www.website.com/studentinformation?id=$1">$1</a>'));
});
```

[Fiddle working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rsdt5a21/2/) - this is not optimized, just straightforward code.

Comment: He said 6 characters and gave an example or two like "John sid: CA1001". You need to tweak that regex a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

1. get all paragraphs you need to update
2. extract the paragraph contents
3. find all substrings to replace
4. extract ids, build link html and replace substrings from 3 with these links

Check demo - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/uu9ka8gt/  and code below:

```
function replacer(match) {
   var m = match.split(' ')[1];
   return '<a href="http://www.website.com/studentinformation?id=' + m + '">' + m + '</a>';
}

$('p').each( function(index, paraElement) {
   paraElement.innerHTML = paraElement.innerHTML.replace(/sid:.{7}/gi, replacer );
});
```

Comment: So far this works great...   Is there a quicker way to replace the "sid" even if the "sid"  is SiD, SID, siD, and etc., instead of replacing them one by one????

Comment: Yes, you need to add `i` flag to regex so it would ignore case, if that's what you mean. I updated fiddle - [https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/uu9ka8gt/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/uu9ka8gt/)

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in a PHP solution in case you want to handle it server-side.

```
<?php 
// This can be all of your text after you compile it or you could loop
$in = "<p>John likes math.  John sid: CA1001 Susie likes English: Susie sid: CA1002</p>";

// Set up what we're finding and what we will replace it with
$pattern = '/sid: (.{6})/'; 
$replace = 'sid: <a href="http://www.website.com/studentinformation?id=$1">$1</a>'; 

// Filter the text with our parameters
$out = preg_filter( $pattern, $replace, $in ); 

// Dump to the browser
echo $out;
```